# How to optimize VPN connection for low latency / ping

Tags: vpn, latency

I am using a VPN (IPSec) connection to my home router to work on the road and access my home network. Now while having most times a good bandwidth, latency/ping isnt always great. Hence I was wondering what kind of adjustments one could make to try to get the latency down as much as possible - even if on the cost of bandwidth. I'm thinking mostly video calls, not gaming in this regards.

Besides beefing up the hardware to eradicate bottlenecks here, what could one do?

On the client side I am currently using a RaspberryPi 4 with Kernel 6.1
On the VPN server side its a AVM Fritzbox 7590 with the latest OS

Comment: One thing I have tried that sometimes works is to use an MTU of 1492 in the home router.

Comment: When you had bad latency, did you rule out the connection you were on? Hotspots, hotels and the like can be very bad. // Also consider WireGuard.

Comment: I'd say pay attention to getting your MTUs set correctly so that no fragmentation/reassembly is happening. I'd also say make sure your VPN server (and other networking equipment, for that matter) is running CAKE or FQ-CoDel or another respectable SQM algorithm so that you don't have bufferbloat problems causing latency spikes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Anyhow, I guess I should make clear that I do NOT have a problem with the connections performance - I just want to see if it can be made better